# trying to redirect to some page when pressing browser back button but not working

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {  <br/>
    event.preventDefault();  <br/>
    event.returnValue = '';  <br/>
    window.location.href = 'https://google.co.in';  <br/>
    return false;  <br/>
});
```

Comment: Please tell me what type of error you are facing

Comment: there is no error but page is being redirect to previos page

Comment: Answered.Check it,

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify history, and use state to know if user go back

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (event.state && event.state.redirect) {
       window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    }
};
history.replaceState({redirect: true}, "");
history.pushState({redirect: false}, "");
```

Comment: event is not getting triggered

Comment: Does it log "1" on go back ?

    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        console.log(1);
        if (event.state && event.state.redirect) {
            /*window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");*/
        }
    };
    history.replaceState({redirect: true}, "");
    history.pushState({redirect: false}, "");

Comment: i debuged it and it is not stoping iiside the event. tried console.log as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `window.location.href('https://google.co.in')` just replace this with  `window.location.href = 'https://google.co.in';` it will work. location.href is used like this given an link and another method is given below.

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Events that **trigger** the `beforeunload` function:

1. Navigating to another page directly in the browser or via a link.
2. Closing the current browser window or tab page.
3. Reloading the current page.
4. Manipulating the URL of the currently loaded page through the location object from JavaScript.
5. Invoking the window.navigate method.
6. Invoking the window.open or the document.open method to open a document in the same window.

This code prevent the back button and replace the window to google.com

```
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  var historyTraversal = event.persisted || 
                         ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                              window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
  if ( historyTraversal ) {
    // Handle page restore.
   window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
  }
});
```

Comment: after replacing it with window.location.href = 'https://google.co.in'; still redirecting to previous page

Comment: @HemanshuPatel Check if you are doing these things that are mentioned above, then it will redirect you to google.com.in because code it.

Comment: i am just creating the simple demo and my whole page only contains the code i have written in the Question other then that it is just hml head and body without any content

Comment: what are you trying to do?.

Comment: i need to redirect to some page in my project so i created a simple demo page to achieve it then once it is working i wil integrate the code in project

Comment: It means that you want to redirect the user when the user leaves

Comment: i need to redirect to perticular page when back button of browser is pressed. so any and all suggetions are welcome

Comment: the code you gave in that event is triggred at page load time and not triggering when pressing the back button